# How to change the Kibana Refresh Interval in Saved objects window

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

How to change the Kibana Dashboard Refresh interval .

[image]

```
{
"index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "5s"
}
}
```

I have tried the above one, it's not working. Please suggest how to change the Refresh interval. [Kibana dashboard should refresh automatically in every 5 seconds - Kibana 5.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the time filter, you can set the auto-refresh option:

[image]

(picture from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.2/set-time-filter.html), with my modification)

Comment: Thanks it's working.. previously i was looking into the advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the advantanced options consider that time is in ms: so for 5s use 5000 (withous s)

```
"refresh_interval" : "5000"
```